# fuse.js returns an empty array when used with Angular

Tags: angular, fuse.js

I am using fuse.js in my Angular Application. I have added the fuse.js script in my angular.json file and I have added a search script which can iterate all the arrays until I call fuse function. After writing the below function, I see  empty arrays in the console.

```
var fuse = new Fuse(list, options);
var searchResult = fuse.search("searchValue");
console.log(searchResult)
```

Comment: Did you import `Fuse` in your **component.ts** file?

Comment: What is the options? can you add the options passed to Fuse in your code?